# JSON is way faster than Protobuf/gRPC for me, with Go as the server and PHP as the client

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc

Perhaps I've somewhat missed the point of Protobufs, but I spent some time to implement it because I was hoping to gain raw speed compared to my current JSON setup.

My use case is like this: a large, complicated PHP application (not a website), in production and being used heavily. We're now trying to split our application into smaller parts, written in a suitable language for each problem. The first service I have split out does processing and transformations on strings, very domain specific and not very interesting. Involves lots of regex's, custom parsing etc.

I implemented my domain logic in Go, which works beautifully and was very easy to pick up. I attached my logic to a simple JSON API, using Go-Kit. Is a very simple transformation, json encoding simply to something like {"v":"some string usually 10-100 chars"}.

The performance was worse than native PHP which I consider quite acceptable considering the overhead of JSON and the addition of transmitting over a network layer.

However, what really surprised me is that Protobuf has not only been no faster than JSON, but actually slower by 30-50%.

My .proto:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package pb;

option optimize_for = SPEED;

service StringStuff {
  rpc DoStringStuff (StringReq) returns (StringRes) {}
}

message StringReq {
  string in = 1;
}

message StringRes {
  string out = 1;
}
```

I used https://github.com/stanley-cheung/Protobuf-PHP and the generated proto php code. My php client code is like this:

```
$client = new StringClient('localhost:50051', [
'credentials' => \Grpc\ChannelCredentials::createInsecure()]);

$string = new StringReq();
$string->setIn("some string...");
list($reply, $status) = $client->DoStringStuff($string)->wait();
```

It works but to my surprise it is a lot slower than JSON.

My only guess: is it possible the php implementation of Protobufs is so much slower than json_decode that currently PHP makes a very poor client for Protobuf?

Or is it normal for small, simple uses like transmitting a single string that JSON should out perform Protobuf?

Thank you for any and all thoughts.

Comment: This is a [large library](https://github.com/stanley-cheung/Protobuf-PHP/) written in PHP while `json_encode` is written in C++ and has been used by millions and optimized since first added. `json_encode` will be many times faster than any kind of PHP-based packing-system.

Comment: Thanks, that was my guess and it makes a lot of sense. Weighing up the pros and cons of Protobufs is more complicated, because in the end PHP wont be the only client.

From your experience is there any faster way of transmitting in this exact use case than JSON?

Comment: BSON is more compact and used by several database engines. Though it's just Binary JSON so doesn't support schemas like Protobufs.

Comment: How are you benchmarking?  Getting accurate, believable benchmark results is notoriously difficult.

Comment: What are you exactly comparing? If you will just look at one call, then JSON with raw tcp will be faster than Grpc/Protobuf with http2 as additional overhead. 
Grpc will shine and most likely outperform JSON when looking at streaming and many messages/calls.

Comment: My benchmark used php's microtime to calculate the difference in time at the end of a sequence of calls and the time before. I tried for 1, 10, 100, 1000, 10,000, and 100,000 calls. CURL with JSON decode (a C++ extension as explained above) was always faster than Protobuf/gRPC. I fiddled around a lot to try to find a way to make Protobufs faster, even once, thinking my benchmark was simply unreliable. But at no point could I get it to go faster or even comparable.

Comment: This makes sense especially if your applications are hosted on a network with good throughput. Protobuf performs compression, which is great at reducing throughput but at the cost of CPU cycles. JSON should take up more bandwidth, but less CPU cycles to deserialize than Protobuf. So as long as the network is unburdened, JSON *should* beat Protobuf  in speed.

Comment: Protobuf supports php c exntension: https://pecl.php.net/package/protobuf

Answer (score 5):

The native PHP implementation of `protobuf`, which you install with `composer require google/protobuf` is *much slower* than the [protobuf C extension](https://pecl.php.net/package/protobuf). To get any real performance out of gRPC you need to install the protobuf C extension:

```
pecl install protobuf
```

and enable it in `php.ini`

```
extension=protobuf.so
```

This does all the serialization/deserialization in C rather than in PHP, which going to be many times faster than the PHP version.